# How to south migrate a forked heroku database

Tags: heroku, django-south, database-migration

Before [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) migrating our heroku production db, I thought of trying the migrations on a forked db, to see if they complete successfully. Is this at all possible with heroku?

The standard command for migrating is:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate [app]
```

but `manage.py` would direct to our production db of course. How would I go about making it migrate the forked db?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a staging environment, which is simply another (free) heroku app, linked to your forked or duplicated database. There you can push your new code and migrate, exactly as you would with your production env.

Here's [heroku's explanation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#starting-with-a-production-app) on how to do that.